# result array put into .txt PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I already have code what is working, check below :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

if($h = fopen('file.txt', 'a')) {

fputcsv($h,$row);

fclose($h);

}
}
```

And output is in this case:

```
11:11:11:11:11:11
22:22:22:22:22:22
33:33:33:33:33:33
```

I need output to be :

```
11:11:11:11:11:11,22:22:22:22:22:22,33:33:33:33:33:33
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that your while loop will iterate every single time that there is a row of data. Typically, you want to avoid opening a file, writing to it, then closing it, opening, writing, closing, etc...

Generally it's a good idea to clump all of the data together, and then write it.

In addition, fputcsv() only puts a comma on single array values.

The solution is to add everything into one array, and then run fputcsv():

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row['mac'];
}

if($h = fopen('file.txt', 'a')) {

    fputcsv($h,$data);

    fclose($h);
}
```

*Note: you will need to replace 'mac' in $row['mac'] with your mySQL column name*

---

I have tested this with a mysql db, and it successfully outputs (to file.txt):

```
11:11:11:11:11:11,22:22:22:22:22:22,33:33:33:33:33:33
```

Comment: Now i checked with my whole code, and file make me problem because it has one clear row

1 11:11:11:11:11:11,22:22:22:22:22:22,33:33:33:33:33:33
2 
I mean i just need one backspace from last point...

Do you have idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fputcsv which adds a line break every time, you can use fwrite:

```
$h = fopen('file.txt', 'a')
if ($h) {
  $count = 0;
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if ($count !== 0) {
      fwrite($h, ',');
    }
    fwrite($h, $row);
    $count++;
  }
  fclose($h);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's use a memory, to store data:

```
if($h = fopen('file.txt', 'a')) {

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

$rows[] = join(":", $row);

}

$data = join(",", $rows);

fwrite($h,$data);
fclose($h);

}
```